# Does ”A car drives” sound natural?

Tags: verbs

I have encountered the following sentence on the Internet:

> Model S hit truck while driving with autopilot on.

Model S is the name of a car produced by Tesla Inc.
I think that the subject of the subordinate clause is Model S and that it is better to use a verb "travel" or "move" instead of "drive".  Is this usage of "drive" is natural for native speakers?

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, but drive sounds awful here. **Travel** is a very good option. **Going** is another option possible, however I wouldn't use it.

Comment: It *is* a sentence with both a subject and predicate and the form of a main clause, but it's not really an example of Standard English.  Instead, it's written with an elliptical style known as *headlinese*.  In headlinese, certain words are typically left out, especially articles and forms of *be*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb drive is also  an intransitive verb meaning to move along or advance quickly.  For example:

Your Ford car drives really well.

We could hear the truck driving along the highway (The Free Dictionary).

So the sentence  "Model S hit a/the truck while driving with autopilot on" 
is grammatical